# openstack attach volume to instance had problem but shown on linux with lsblk command but can not mount and can not delete with any command

Tags: linux, openstack, volume

I have a problem with **attaching volume** to instances on `Openstack`.

e.g. the volume had problem to attach, this volume shown on OpenStack Cli by `openstack volume list` , but does not attach properly on instances (Linux instance ) and on Linux cli only shown with `lsblk` command and **can not mount and delete** with any ways . ( `fdisk` , `cfdisk` , `sfdisk` , ... ) .

Help me to **delete this volume from instance** because with this problem i can not attach any other volume to this instance.

Comment: If possible shut down the instance, then try to detach the volume. If that doesn't work, check the cinder-volume.log and nova-compute.log file for more details why detaching fails. The last resort would be to try to reset the volume's state to "detached" and then trying to delete it.

Comment: thanks , 
i dont have any problem to delete volumes. my real problem on instance that does not take any action on this volume and only shown with lsblk command. this is log of nova-Compute :

`File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 560, in attachDeviceFlags
if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainAttachDeviceFlags() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid: target vdc already exists`

cinder-log:
`INFO cinder.volume.manager [req-5f0e6307-546bff58821114bfdba41a4aefa821 - default default] Terminate volume connection completed successfully`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you execute `openstack server add volume` when the instance is `shutoff`, and fixed the error ?

If not, try this:

- check the log of `nova-libvirt` and `cinder-volume`, and then try to `restart` them, because of this error tips: **libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid**.
- get the instance status info by `openstack server show`, and check if the volume works.
- if volume not works, try `openstack server reboot --hard` the instance, and check the status info again.

I had met the issue seems like this, because of the incorrect **authorization** in the `cinder-volume` back end -- `ceph`.

Comment: @JohnnWorker You are welcome, have you fixed it, what’s the true problem?

Comment: thank you sooo much . @VictorLee
your reply solve my problem.
when instance is off and then restart libvirtd.service , i is ok and can attach volume to them.
thanks in adance.

Comment: yes it fixed. with restart libvirtd service on compute ( than instance on it ) and then shutdown instance and attach volume with Openstack server add volume command. then it fixed .

Comment: nice, maybe restart the relevant process will resolve some problems.

Comment: @JohnnWorker one more thing, if this answer had resolved your question, you could accept it or vote up it for helpful. Check from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the volume itself from Openstack side?

Have you tried rebooting and see if device is registered on linux instance in dmesg?

Comment: thanks for your reply ...

@Omar Munoz  ... 

yes i delete the Volume from OpenStack and it delete without any problem from Cinder .
but yet it shown on instance with lsblk command. then i restart  the instance , after that this message shown on dmesg :

 `117.936690] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev vdc, sector 0
[  117.938839] Buffer I/O error on dev vdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  117.941495] Buffer I/O error on dev vdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  117.943986]  vdc: unable to read partition table`

Comment: Were there any services accessing the now removed block device, e.g. LVM? If that's the case you should cleanup any references of that volume within the instance until it boots up without errors. Then you can attach a new volume and see if the issue is resolved.